# Ceiling stain and potential water leak

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drywall, ceiling, leak

I recently opened a few window blinds, that I had not opened in a while.  When doing so, I observed a stain on my kitchen ceiling.  I’m not sure how long it has been there, as I only saw it with the added light.

I live in a 3 story townhome and this area is directly below a full bathroom, with two sinks.

I know one of the sinks had recently developed a leak (in the trap area), so I had opted not to use it until I got it repaired.  I believe I had found the issue before it developed into a problem and was lucky enough to have had a tray underneath that actually caught the water.

Sadly, I’m not sure if this is the culprit behind the ceiling stain.

I’m trying to determine what I should do.  Should I monitor the stain and see if it gets bigger?  Should I contact a plumper immediately?  If it’s just the trap issue, I think I can repair that myself.  If it’s something more serious, I’m guessing I’ll need a professional.

In general, for a small ceiling stain, is it common to replace dry wall or do any further inspection of damage?

Update: looks like the water was from the toilet. From looking online, I’m guessing it’s the wax seal?  I have someone coming to fix the toilet tomorrow.  Hopefully I caught it before any serious damage. :(

[image]

Comment: just in time, the damage is not big, it could be just painted over, if the leaking has stoped

Comment: If the drywall is soft if you press on it, it might need repairing instead of just prime and paint to cover the stain.  It seems small so leak is new or tiny.  Can you locate the spot above the stain in the bathroom?  Is it in the centre of the floor or under the sinks/tub/toilet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Ask-er has resolved the question by discovering an unrelated problem and solution.

Comment: Please don't "update" your _question_ with the _answer_. Instead, put the answer down below in the "Your Answer" box, then, when the system will allow it, please click the check mark so that others will know that this has a solution. That saves the time of people looking to answer the question, and it helps others who may be in a similar situation know that this does have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Trace out the spot on some tracing paper so you can tell if the spot's getting bigger. Observe for awhile. I've had luck removing stains by dabbing some bleach lightly over the stain. Curious,  what's the hole saw plug for? What are those pin holes in the stain for? I wouldn't be replacing drywall yet. It could be an old stain. Keep an eye on it.

Comment: It was from the pins in a moisture detector.  I used it shortly before I took the photos.  About an hour after this post, I saw water dripping from the holes, so I actually took a small screwdriver and poked it all the way through, just to help drain the water.  I’ve also stopped using that toilet, until it’s fixed.